# Metrics, smells: How to find longest (in lines of code) methods in my legacy product java repo?

Tags: java, static-analysis, metrics, static-code-analysis

What is the simplest way to find longest (in terms of lines of code) methods in a legacy java code base?

We use gradle and IntelliJ IDEA so ideally a plugin for one of these.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [JArchitect](https://www.jarchitect.com), it provides out of the box many code smells rules and you can easily customize the rules as you want using CQLinq the code query language used to create the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do a bit of research/googling on "static code analysis" and you'll soon find things like [pmd](https://pmd.github.io) and [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net).

For tracking these reports over time there's enterprise solutions like [sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org)

All of these have gradle integration